# Function fails when document is changed in MS Word when generating Table of Content

Tags: vba, ms-word, tableofcontents

'''
When I used the code below it works in the document where it was created. If I change documents, it fails. does anyone know why?
'''

```
'
Sub AddTOC() 'Need to find how to stop going in error on doc change
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToLine, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=0
        Application.Templates( _
        "C:\Users\Sean Celestin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1033\16\Built-In 
Building Blocks.dotx" _
        ).BuildingBlockEntries("Automatic Table 1").Insert Where:=Selection.Range _
        , RichText:=True
        
        Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
End Sub
```

'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does essentially the same thing without embedding the Table of Contents in the container used by the Building Block Entry. That container imposes a significant performance hit when the TOC is updated. By not using Selection, the code is also more efficient.

```
Sub AddTOC()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument
  .Range(0, 0).Text = vbCr & Chr(12)
  .Fields.Add .Range(0, 0), wdFieldEmpty, "TOC \o ""1-3"" \h \z \u", False
  .Range(0, 0).Text = "Contents" & vbCr
  .Range.Paragraphs.First.Style = "TOC Heading"
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```